# Working with JSON and MySql to gather values into variables

Tags: arrays, json, database, arduino, esp32

I'm working on a project with involves gathering info from my `.json` file into a variable in my Arduino sketch, but I'm having problems when it comes to adding values into the variables when I have more than 1 value. If I have more than 1 value I can't store it into the new variable.
So this is how my JSON file looks:

```
 [{"AutoIncrement":"1","Aparelho":"LED","Status":"0"}, 
 {"AutoIncrement":"2","Aparelho":"LED1","Status":"1"}]
```

This is my Arduino sketch:

```
    char json[500];
    payload.replace(" ", "");
    payload.replace("\n", "");
    payload.trim();
    payload.remove(0,1);
    payload.toCharArray(json, 500);

    StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
    deserializeJson(doc, json);

    //Isso nao depende do nome no banco de dados, depende do nome dentro de action.php
    //LED 1
    int id = doc["AutoIncrement"];
    const char* nome = doc["Aparelho"];
    int stat = doc["Status"];

    //LED 2
    int id1 = doc["AutoIncrement"];
    const char* nome1 = doc["Aparelho"];
    int stat1 = doc["Status"];

    Serial.println(id);
    Serial.println(nome);
    Serial.println(stat);

    Serial.println(id1);
    Serial.println(nome1);
    Serial.println(stat1);

    if (stat == 1)
    {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    }
    else if (stat == 0)
    {
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
    }
```

This is the output:

```
 Statuscode: 200
 [{"AutoIncrement":"1","Aparelho":"LED","Status":"0"}, 
 {"AutoIncrement":"2","Aparelho":"LED1","Status":"1"}]
 1
 LED
 0
 //This was suppose to be 2, LED1, 0:
 1
 LED
 0
```

Comment: ```JsonArray array = doc.as<JsonArray>(); id1=array[1]["AutoIncrement"]```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON array consists of two JSON objects. You can access the first object with `doc[0]`, and to access the element within the first object, it will be `doc[0]["AutoIncrement"]`.

**Update**

However based on your comment, I realised that your `payload` is actually an Arduino String class object, if your print it out, it will look like this:

```
"[{\"AutoIncrement\":\"1\",\"Aparelho\":\"LED\",\"Status\":\"0\"}, {\"AutoIncrement\":\"2\",\"Aparelho\":\"LED1\",\"Status\":\"1\"}]";
```

And the code that try to converting the String object to a c char array actually causing an invalid JSON object. Change your code as below:

```
// converting String payload into a c char array
int length = payload.length() + 1;
char json[length];
payload.toCharArray(json, length);

StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
deserializeJson(doc, json);

//LED 1
int id = doc[0]["AutoIncrement"];
const char* nome = doc[0]["Aparelho"];
int stat = doc[0]["Status"];

//LED 2
int id1 = doc[1]["AutoIncrement"];
const char* nome1 = doc[1]["Aparelho"];
int stat1 = doc[1]["Status"];

Serial.println(id);
Serial.println(nome);
Serial.println(stat);

Serial.println(id1);
Serial.println(nome1);
Serial.println(stat1);
```

This will produce the correct results as:

```
1
LED
0
2
LED1
1
```

Comment: I'm getting 0 as reposnse for all of the variables

Comment: I re-look at your code and I know why now, see my updated answer.